# Can IEnumerable and IQueryable be Union?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I tried to Union IQueryable and IEnumerable but got this error

*Union(__p_2)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.*

and tried many different writing methods but it doesn't work. So can IEnumerable and IQueryable be Union?

My data looks like the following:

```
var users = new List<Person>().AsQueryable();
var user = GetUsersByXXX(XXX, YYY);   // return IQueryable<Person>
var userExtra = GetUsersExtraByXXX(XXX, YYY); // return IEnumerable<Person>

if (userExtra.Any())
{
  users = user.Union(userExtra);
}    

return await users.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(x => x.NAME ).ToListAsync();
```

class

```
public class Person
{
    public string CODE { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string PHONE { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what is `endApproveExtra`?

Comment: @GuruStron sorry it mean userExtra

Comment: `new List<T>().AsQueryable();` doesn't make any sense. Especially if you immediately overwrite it. Also, ask yourself why `GetUsersByXXX` and `GetUsersExtraByXXX` return different collection types. That's definitely a code smell.

Comment: you state returns IQueryable<T> and return IEnumerable<T> however niether function has been told what T is so this can't be correct

Comment: @JHBonarius `new List<T>().AsQueryable();` because it must `return await users.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(x => x.NAME).ToListAsync()` . This is the project that I inherited. because code smell i'm refactoring code

Comment: @MikeT I have edited T to class.

Comment: @Puthxii that is a sign of bad design. The function `GetUsersByXXX` is too generic. [Such a generic repository pattern is a code smell](https://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern/). Instead you should have a method that encapsulates everything, e.g. `GetNotTrackedUsersByXXXSortedByName[List]`

Comment: @Puthxii oh, now I see it's worse. You want to do `users.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(x => x.NAME).ToListAsync()` _after_ the union! That `IEnumerable userExtra` has already been enumerated, so that just doesn't make sense. The order of operations and responsibilities have been messed up. This is a sign that the code is turning into spaghetti. You should really clean it up, else you'll end up with an unmaintainable legacy application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IQueryable<T>` interface already implements `IEnumerable<T>`, you just need to cast to `IEnumerable<T>` to ensure you use the linq-to-objects implementation.

```
var users = GetUsersByXXX(XXX, YYY).AsEnumerable() // "cast" it
    .Union(GetUsersExtraByXXX(XXX, YYY));
```

The added check to see if the "extra" users is empty is unnecessary. If it's already empty, the union would essentially be a noop.

Answer (score 5):

You must understand those two things are two different concepts:

- An [`IQueryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable) is an interface that *"Provides functionality to evaluate queries against a specific data source"*
- An [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1) is an interface that *"Exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a collection"*.

An `IQueryable` can be turned into `IEnumerable` by calling [`AsEnumerable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.asenumerable).

Note, that an `IQueryable` can be a non-evaluated expression. I.e. the data has not been retrieved from the database. By calling something like `ToList` or `AsEnumerable`, you enumerate, thus evaluate it. The normal (synrchonous) methods will block until that's finished. That's why there are also `ToListAsync` and `AsAsyncEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is caused by an error where the query you're generating cannot be translated into SQL. It would appear that `IQueryable<T>.Union()` cannot be translated to SQL and the error is thrown.

You would need to work around this by either calling one of the methods mentioned in the error to force the union to be performed in .NET by having Entity Framework retrieve the full set of data for `GetUsersByXXX()` first and then performs the union in memory.

```
var users = new List<T>().AsQueryable();
var user = GetUsersByXXX(XXX, YYY);   // return IQueryable<T>
var userExtra = GetUsersExtraByXXX(XXX, YYY); // return IEnumerable<T>

if (userExtra.Any())
{
  users = user.AsEnumerable().Union(userExtra);
}
```